# How can I get the creation date of folder in Ambari HDFS with Linux commands?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ambari

Yo,

I'm trying to get the creation date of several folders.
If the date is 14 days ago, I want to remove it.

BUT, I can't find appropriate hdfs command to get the creation date.
I thought of:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /mainFolder/subFolder
```

and then parse the output. This is very unprofessional, must be easier way.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `stat` command with the default format. It will print out the modification date of the provided file/folder. See the [File System Shell Hadoop Reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat) for more information.

For example:

```
$hadoop fs -stat /user
2016-03-28 17:14:53
```

Comment: According to the doc, "If the format is not specified, %y is used by default". This means this will only prompt the modification date, not the creation date.